# When do relation-broken hooks get triggered?

Tags: juju

Here (https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/reference-charm-hooks#[name]-relation-broken), the section titled "-relation-broken" explains two scenarios when a relation-broken hook is triggered.

> 1. It will only be called after every necessary -departed hook has been run
> 2. It is important to note that the -broken hook might run even if no other units have ever joined the relation. This is not a bug: even if no remote units have ever joined, the fact of the unit's participation can be detected in other hooks via the relation-ids tool, and the -broken hook needs to execute to give the charm an opportunity to clean up any optimistically-generated configuration.

The 1st scenario specifically says which events triggers the relation-broken hook (i.e., when all the particular relations with the remote service-units are destroyed).

But the 2nd scenario does not specifically say when this hook get triggered. Can anyone provide an example which events trigger the second scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to deploy services without any units and to relate to services which may not have any units. If you were to then remove this relation the relation would have been broken but no units were joined.

Comment: regarding "It is possible to deploy services without any units", if we use "juju deploy", it generates a new service and the initial service-unit. Do we deploy services without any units by using "juju remove-unit" command?

Comment: @DenisWeerasiri It's currently only possible via the API (and the GUI). The syntax would be `juju deploy my-service -n 0` but  there is a bug in the CLI: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1262750